# Please help identify late 1970's Cthulhu Mythos Sci Fi comic

Tags: story-identification, comics, cthulhu-mythos

I'm trying to find some info on a story which was part of a comic that I bought in the late 1970's. I cannot remember the title of the comic, the story or anything about the artist. But I vividly remember details of the story. It was all in black and white. The story was about human space explorers who land on an alien world and gradually get killed in more and more horrible ways, one being torn in half by a big tentacled beast. At the end, the last 2 surviving explorers break into a huge hall which seems to be the control center of the planet. In the hall, they find many huge sculptures of many gods and religious figures from many planets, including, Jesus, Buddha, and Mohammed, all of whom are hundreds of feet high. One of these figures is Cthulhu, or a very Cthulhu-like octopus-head humanoid god. One of the guys gets totally disgusted by the Cthulhu sculpture and shoots it with a gun or attacks it somehow, and it begins emitting a smoke-like, black, corrosive gas. One of the guys sticks his hand into it and his hand melts. The black corrosive smoke eventually overcomes them, as well as the entire planet. The story ends with a black square and a biblical-type quote "In the beginning was darkness..."

If anybody can help ID this story, or its origins, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Based on the time frame, media (comic), content (adult) and story (psychedelic), this is likely from an issue of Heavy Metal.

Comment: In fact, try the October 1979 issue. It is a Lovecraft special issue.

Comment: Has to be Lovecraft if Cthulhu is involved

Comment: The Heavy Metal issue is online here:https://imgur.com/gallery/uifAz  Sorry, false lead, only partly. But story titles shown don't suggest story in account given.

Comment: Actually, Lovecraft was cool with people using his material in their own stories, even professionally published ones.